# Wordpress- how to achieve?: search bar on main page, then display a table filtered by the search bar input, on a different page

Tags: wordpress, search, filter, searchbar

this is supposed to be done in Wordpress, so if there are any plugins that do this, it would be great. If not, i'd like to code that.

I would like a search bar on the main page. When a user types something and presses enter, i want to direct him/her to a different page with a table (which is available in a wordpress plugin, and also has filtering functions), with the input word from the main page's search bar already in the table's search, and filtering the current table.

Not sure what would be the best and easiest way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax Search for WooCommerce
check this plugin if you are using the woocommerce plugin

Comment: I'm not using woocommerce, but ill take a look, thanks.